# Fundamental group of octagon with opposide side identified

Tags: algebraic-topology, surfaces, fundamental-groups

One of the homework tasks my professor gave me is to calculate all the possible fundamental group of an octagon with the opposite sides identified. I think that I found an answer but I'm not that confident about it.
My proof revolves around two things:

1. The classification of the connected space
2. The Euler characteristic of my octagon

Since I'm identifying the opposite sides my octagon is made of 1 vertex, 4 edges and just one 2-simplex, so its euler characteristic is $-2$. That property doesn't change with different side orientation.
At this point I know that any closed connected surface is homeomorphic to one of the following two:
$$T_n=S^2\#\underbrace{T\#...\#T}_n\;\;\;\;\;\operatorname{with}\;n\geq 0$$
$$P_m=S^2\#\underbrace{P^2\mathbb{R}\#...\#P^2\mathbb{R}}_m\;\;\;\;\;\operatorname{with}\;m\geq 1$$
But since $\chi(T_n)=2-2n$ and $\chi(P_m)=2-m$ it turns out that the only cases where my octagon can be homeomorphic to one of those two is if n=2 or m=4.
At that point I can use the Van Kampen theorem to find what their fundamental groups are.

Does this make sense to you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Contrary to what you state, the count of vertices of the octagon quotient (namely the quotient space obtained by identifying opposite sides of the octagon) depends very much on the orientations of the sides.

You can see this by writing out possible "gluing words".

For example, using the gluing word $abcda^{-1}b^{-1}c^{-1}d^{-1}$ it does follow that the octagon quotient has only 1 vertex and therefore has Euler characteristic equal to $1-4+1=-2$. With more work you can see that this surface is indeed homeomorphic to $T_2$.

But consider next the gluing word $abcdabcd$. Using this you will see that the octagon quotient has $4$ vertices, not $1$ vertex. The Euler characteristic is therefore equal to $4-4+1=1$. So this octagon quotient certainly is not homeomorphic to $T_2$ nor to $P_4$. I'll leave it to you to work which which of the $T_n$'s or $P_m$'s this surface is homeomorphic to, and then to continue your exercise by calculating all the other possibilities.